# C# + get list from list

Tags: c#, linq, list

I am relatively new to C#. I am trying to get List from List in next manner:

Model Data:

```
string productId
string productName
string depotName
int quantity

List< Data > FullList
```

example:

> prod1  |  product1  |  depot1  |  1.00
>
> prod1  |  product1  |  depot2  |  2.00
>
> prod1  |  product1  |  depot3  |  0.00
>
> prod2  |  product2  |  depot1  |  2.00
>
> prod2  |  product2  |  depot2  |  5.00

After I got list like this, I want to create one more list from this one in next manner:

```
List< Data > NewList
```

> prod1  |  product1  |  depot1,depot2  |  3.00
>
> prod2  |  product2  |  depot1,depot2  |  7.00

I want to group items in list by `product_id, sum(quantity)` and concat string of depot names.

I try and get to some point (grouping and getting distinct values using `GroupBy(x => x.product_id)` and `Distinct()`, but I can not get `sum(quantity)`.

Can somebody help me with this.

Thank You very much.

Comment: And you think this unredable post is a question?

Comment: Sorry, what is unreadable? Can You see letters, text that I wrote... or there is question marks or some strange data?

Comment: Have you looked at your question after posting? Are you kidding? BTW: I am not the one who needs help. So beign arrogant will not help you much.

Comment: I looked at it.

I do not intend to argue and spent time like this.
In my life, I like to call things with proper names.

If something is "unreadable", then, my guess is, that you can not read it.
If you can read it, maybe you don`t like form of question that is written.

I noted example of model-class, example of 2 Lists, example what I am trying to get, and wrote in clear sentences what I try what I get and where I need help.

I would appreciate to get help on the forum.

Comment: English is not my native language, So I might have  worded it wrong with "unredable", but that doesn't change the quality of your question. -4 should show something to you.

Comment: @Matt Rowland, thank You (if You format my question). This is first time I am writing here and I didn`t know things about formating. I will try to get it well next time I wrote something.

I am not sure how You grade quality of questions. If the formating of text from person that is first time writing something is for -4, then I miss the point.

Comment: Stack Overflow requests that you provide examples of what you tried. You provide a small portion of that but more would be better. The community also prefers evidence that you tried, and in most cases the error message you are receiving is best. This will also help everyone in diagnosing what is happening, even without running the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var summary = FullList
    .GroupBy(p => p.product_id)
    .Select(g => new {
       product_id = g.product_id,
       product_name = g.First().product_name,
       quantity = g.Sum(p => p.quantity)
     })
     .ToList();
```

As an exercise think about [Concat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb302894(v=vs.100).aspx) for getting all the depot names.

Comment: Thank You. Your post is clean, short and give me answer that I looking for.

Also, I would like to thanks to other people for usefull comments.

For getting concatenate depot names I did not use Concat(). I resolve it in this way:

`depotName = g.Select(q => q.depotName).Aggregate((e,r) => e + "," + r)`

Comment: And, because I neede only depot names where quantity is more then 0, I added:


`depotName = g.Where(z => z.quantity>0).Select(q => q.depotName).Aggregate((e,r) => e + "," + r)`

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

This implementation doesn't use linq but it does the job right. Not sure about how good is the performance when accessing large amounts of data,

Code Behind:

```
List<Data> data = new List<Data>()
            {
                new Data() { productId = "prod1", productName = "product1", depotName = "depot1", quantity = 1 },
                new Data() { productId = "prod1", productName = "product1", depotName = "depot2", quantity = 2 },
                new Data() { productId = "prod1", productName = "product1", depotName = "depot3", quantity = 0 },
                new Data() { productId = "prod2", productName = "product2", depotName = "depot1", quantity = 2 },
                new Data() { productId = "prod2", productName = "product2", depotName = "depot2", quantity = 5 },
            };

            List<Data> newData = new List<Data>();

            foreach(var d in data)
            {
                Data newDataRecord = newData.FirstOrDefault(nd => nd.productId == d.productId);
                if (newDataRecord != null)
                {
                    int newDataRecordIndex = newData.IndexOf(newDataRecord);
                    if(!newDataRecord.depotName.Contains(d.depotName))
                    {
                        newData[newDataRecordIndex].depotName += string.Format(",{0}", d.depotName); // Append to the existing depotName
                    }
                    newData[newDataRecordIndex].quantity += d.quantity; // Add quantity
                }
                else
                {
                    newData.Add(d);
                }
            }
```

Model:

```
public class Data
    {
        public string productId { get; set; }
        public string productName { get; set; }
        public string depotName { get; set; }
        public int quantity { get; set; }
    }
```

Output:

prod1 | product1 | depot1,depot2,depot3 | 3.00

prod2 | product2 | depot1,depot2 | 7.00

Comment: You could get downvotes for answer without any explanations. "Try this" is really not useful text in answer...

Comment: Ok thanks for the reminder. I added some info to it